# when do norm-continuous unitary representations separate points of a group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, unitary-representations

Recently I found in the web a [discussion](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6098298) on the following question:

`For which locally compact group G its norm-contunuous unitary representations separate points of G?`

(A unitary representation $\pi:G\to B(H)$ is said to be *norm-continuous* if it is continuous with respect to the usual norm topology on $B(H)$.)

As far as I understand, this happens quite rarely, however, there are some general results, in particular, Julia Kuznetsova writes in one of her [papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.1409), that every SIN-group $G$ has this property (see also a discussion in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66394/norm-continuous-infinite-dimenisonal-representation-of-a-lie-group/66443#66443)).

I wonder if there is a criterion? Is the class of locally compact groups $G$ satisfying this condition described?

Comment: How important is the generality of all locally compact groups to you? If you restrict attention to *connected Lie groups*, then Corollary 5 of I. M. Singer, Uniformly continuous representations of Lie groups (1952: http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=49201) suggests that only the products (compact Lie group) $\times$ (vector group) will satisfy your condition. (These are, I guess, precisely the connected Lie SIN-groups?)

Comment: François, actually I'd like to have a theorem for general situation (not only for Lie groups, but a description for this subclass among all locally compact groups)... Is it possible that there is a gap between SIN-groups and those I am interested in?.. (Thank you for the reference anyway!)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I think your last guess is correct (a theorem of Freudenthal and Weil IIRC)