# Categorical setting for representations of topological groups in classical sense

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory

Let $G$ be a topological group. A representation of $G$ in a Banach space $V$ is a continuous function $G\times V\to V$.

[This MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122208/223002) asks about a possible categorical framework for representations of topological groups. As [remarked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122208/what-is-the-categorical-perspective-on-representations-of-topological-groups#comment282941_122244) the notion there recovers norm-continuous representations, which are emphasized [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66394/69037) as distinct from the definition above.

Is there a pleasant categorical framework for representations in the above sense? In the discrete case, the perspectives of functors from $\mathbf BG$ and of modules over group algebras are very satisfying.

**Added.** I tried to read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0435) by Bernstein, but I understood very little. As a novice to representation theory I am very interested in having "correct" definitions, from a maximally geometric perspective. Any references would be appreciated. I don't mind highly categorical language as long as it's rigorous and recovers the notion of continuous representation described above.

(It would be nice to have a formal version of the definition Bernstein proposes.)

Comment: Scholze and Clausen's condensed mathematics seems to be the right answer for a large class of topological groups.